# Removing text from various document types

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am writing a C# asp.net web application that receives CV's in various formats i.e. doc, docx, pdf, text, etc.

I was wondering if there was a simple way I could remove certain information from the document not matter what file type it is and then pass on the edited file to the end user?

The information to be removed will be held in a string

Comment: No, there is no simple way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to parse each file type using separate APIs.

- .docx can be parsed using: http://docx.codeplex.com/
- .pdf can be parsed using: http://www.pdfsharp.net/
- etc.

Comment: I thought this would be the case

Comment: You could create an abstract base class, an later implement the methods needed to handle the different types of documents.

Comment: That would certainly be the cleanest way to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a streamreader (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.aspx) to read through the document, you could use the ReadToEnd function to store everything in a string, then use the function:

```
 MyString.Replace("Something to replace", "");
```

to remove the matches. If the file formats cannot be read in as a string, you'll have to consider different options. However, there are likely faster solutions given the file formats, and it's likely not stored as simply.

Comment: The problem with this is .doc files may have markup in the middle of the string you are searching for. Text rendered in Word as `Something to replace` will likely not be stored in the .doc file as `Something to replace`.

Comment: DOCX is a compressed file containing XML. PDF and DOC are both binary formats. I think that this approach would be likely to fail...

Comment: Fair enough, I suppose you could read in the byte array and try to parse from there, but that's not exactly a simple solution :p